# Sign in to asp.net MVC 5 website with and admin account using Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory, windows-authentication, iis-10

I am creating an internal website using asp.net MVC 5, hosted on Windows Server 2016 and IIS version 10, using Windows Authentication. Part of the site will be used for System Administrators, so they will need to use their admin account instead of their regular account. The problem I am running into is I can’t get an admin account to authenticate with the website.

It will probably help to have an explanation of how our administrators’ accounts are setup. I’ll use John Doe here as an example user with an admin account. John Do has a regular AD account with the samaccountname ‘jdoe’. He also has a System Administrator account with the samaccountname ‘jdoe-sa’. This is government related and therefore we are using Smart Cards for authentication to Active Directory. Regular accounts still have passwords they use for some systems, but admin accounts have the bit flipped: ‘Microsoft Passport or smart card is required for interactive log on’. Both the regular account and the admin account have the certificate for the smart card set in the altSecurityIdentities attribute in AD. So in other words, both accounts, ‘jdoe’ and ‘jdoe-sa’ are tied to the same smart card. The way that we specify which one to use at login is by using the Username hint field under the PIN field. When John Doe wants to use his regular account, he types ‘jdoe’ in the username hint field and when he wants to use his admin account he types ‘jdoe-sa’ in the username hint field, and the PIN is the same for either account.

The problem is, when authenticating with the website, it does not give the option to specify an account tied to the smart card, it just defaults to the regular account and because of this, I have been unable to authenticate with an admin account. I have tried opening the browser as the admin account, but it still defaults to the regular account. I have also tried logging in the to computer as the admin account, but when I go to the site, it still defaults to the regular account. My next thought process was to impersonate the admin account, but I have yet to find any way of doing impersonation without using the user’s password and as I mentioned already, we have these accounts setup to use smart card instead. I am aware that there is still a password in play for the admin accounts, but they are managed by Active Directory and are not known to the user.

Is there any way that I can have a user authenticate with their admin account either through Windows authentication natively somehow or through impersonation, or some other way? Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have a good solution, is it possible to use Integrated Windows Authentication to solve this problem? https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/windows/use-integrated-windows-authentication-with-your-portal.htm

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into the link you provided. I Appreciate the response.